# ParseObject.save() does not save on the server

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, synchronization

In my Activity I init the [Parse service](https://parse.com) to sync data between devices:

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());
ParseObject.registerSubclass(Point.class);
Parse.initialize(this, "MY_APP_ID", "MY_CLIENT_KEY");
ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```

I have this class

```
@ParseClassName("Point")
public class Point extends ParseObject {    
    public static ParseQuery<Point> getQuery() {
        return ParseQuery.getQuery(Point.class);
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return getString("number");
    }
    public void setNumber(String number) {
        put("number", number);
    }

    public String getAreaId() {
        return getString("areaId");
    }    
    public void setAreaId(String areaId) {
        put("areaId", areaId);
    }

    public ParseGeoPoint getLocation() {
        return getParseGeoPoint("location");
    }    
    public void setLocation(ParseGeoPoint point) {
        put("location", point);
    }

    public boolean isDirty() {
        return getBoolean("isDirty");
    }    
    public void setIsDirty(boolean isDirty) {
        put("isDirty", isDirty);
    }
}
```

Now I want to sync the data with the server.

```
NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (ni != null && ni.isConnected()) {
    ParseAnonymousUtils.logInInBackground();
    try {
        point.save();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        //handle errors
    }
}
```

Calling `save()` does not throw an exception, but it neither saves anything to the server.

#### I updated my question.

I can save another simple ParseObject to the server. But I can't save the `Point`. There must be something special about that class.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure that `ni.isConnected()´ is not false?

Comment: You catched the exception, but did not print it via "e.printStackTrace();" on "area.save();"

Comment: I put a breakpoint in it. No exception is thrown. And this is just a reduced code segment for better readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I had a field called `isDirty` that indicates if I already saved the object to the cloud.

Since `ParseObject`s do have the same getter and setter, I unknowingly overrided the field which Parse did not like that.

I had to change that field to another name and then it worked.